# rspec for solr search: less_than / greater_than scenarios

Tags: rspec-rails, sunspot-solr

I am writing controller spec for solr search. 
This is my controller

```
 @search = Plan.available_plans.search do
  fulltext params[:zip_code] do
  end

  all_of do
    with :status, "active"
    with(:price).greater_than(10)
    with(:end_date).greater_than Time.now
  end
```

And the spec is :

```
it "should list active plans" do  
 get :index
  Sunspot.session.should be_a_search_for(Plan)
  Sunspot.session.should_not have_search_params(:with, :status, "inactive")
end

it "should not list plans with price < 10" do
  get :index
  Sunspot.session.should be_a_search_for(Plan)
  Sunspot.session.should_not have_search_params(:with, :price, :less_than => 10)
end


it "should not list plans that have expired" do
  get :index
  Sunspot.session.should be_a_search_for(Plan)
  Sunspot.session.should_not have_search_params(:with, :end_date, :less_than => Date.today)
end
```

The first one works fine. I searched a lot but could not find a proper syntax that would work to test other scenarios. Plz help me out.

Comment: First of all you search for price greater than 0, but you check than price shouldn't be less than 10 in the test. So in search you assume that price == 1 is ok, but for your all prices from (1..9) range are wrong.

Comment: Did you try a block as a second argument? Sunspot.session.should_not have_search_params(:with) { with(:price). greater_than(0) }

Comment: hey, it worked when dealing with integer values. However if I do the same for end_date, it doesn't work.